# Different NSPredicate behaviour between Simulator and device

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I know I'm doing the 'wrong' thing here, but it worked in all situations except in the Simulator when targeting an iPad Air or Retina - it works on the Simulator for different devices or a supported physical device (6S and Retina tested), but fails on iPad Air or Retina when run in the Simulator.

Latest version of Realm (0.97) and iOS (9.2) and XCode (7.2). To reproduce the problem, here is a VERY contrived example...

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class MyObject: Object {
    dynamic var x: Int64 = 0
    dynamic var y: Int64 = 0
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        print("Realm path: \(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!)")

        let realm = try! Realm()

        try! realm.write({
            realm.deleteAll()
        })

        let myObject = MyObject()
        myObject.x = 1
        myObject.y = 2

        try! realm.write({
            realm.add(myObject)
        })

        let findX: Int64 = 1
        let findY: Int64 = 2

        let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "x == %d and y == %d", findX, findY)
        let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "x == %d", findX)
        let p3 = NSPredicate(format: "x == %lld and y == %lld", findX, findY)

        print("Test 1: Fail on iPad retina in Simulator: \(realm.objects(MyObject).filter(p1).count)")
        print("Test 2: Pass on all platforms: \(realm.objects(MyObject).filter(p2).count)")
        print("Test 3: Pass on all platforms: \(realm.objects(MyObject).filter(p3).count)")

        return true
    }

}
```

When you run this, all of these tests "should" print "1" (and yes, test 3 is the most correct). But, for me at least, the first test returns "0" if run in the Simulator and targeting an iPad Air or Retina. And they work on physical devices.

I know the third test is how it should be coded, but (1) why does the second test work then; and (2) why does this only occur in the Simulator for these specific devices? (And I'll have you know it took quite a while to work out the root cause!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is the format string that you use to construct the `NSPredicate`. You can see this by simplifying your code to the following:

```
let findX: Int64 = 1
let findY: Int64 = 2

let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "x == %d and y == %d", findX, findY)
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "x == %lld and y == %lld", findX, findY)

print(p1)
print(p2)
```

In a 32-bit simulator this prints:

```
x == 1 AND y == 0
x == 1 AND y == 2
```

In a 64-bit simulator it prints:

```
x == 1 AND y == 2
x == 1 AND y == 2
```

This shows that using the format string `x == %d and y == %d` results in a predicate that doesn't express the query that you intend. The reason this happens is that the format specifiers for `p1` do not match the types of the arguments you are passing. In particular, the `%d` format string expects you to pass an `Int` but you're passing an `Int64`. By using `%lld` it correctly looks for the 64-bit values that you are passing.

Comment: I didn't think of printing the predicates, nice. I had not considered 32-bit vs 64-bit differences because both the 'problem' devices are 64-bit. Presumably the Simulator is incorrectly choosing 32-bit for them (I will try and confirm). Nevertheless, it works fine if I use the predicates with NSArray rather than Realm, and odd that findX can cast ok, but findY cannot. I will do some more digging.

Comment: You'll want to verify which architecture you're running the simulator as. I believe that some of them support running as both 32- and 64-bit, and since Xcode doesn't provide a clear UI to select which you can unexpected end up testing your code for a different architecture you expect. I suspect this is how you found that it works for NSArray, since there's no way it could when given an incorrect predicate.

Comment: You're right. Every time I run for iPad Retina, I'm getting a 32-bit architecture in the Simulator, despite it being a 64-bit device. I didn't think I had to care about 32-bit any more, damn. Also, I must have been confused with NSArray working, as it's consistent with Realm. Still, it's a bit rubbish that Apple doesn't do any type checking there. I will accept the answer but also update my question so I don't lead others down the garden path.

Comment: O my god it took me about an hour to figure out I should have used %lld instead of %d :')

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write the predicate like this ?

```
NSPredicate(format: "x == \(findX) and y == \(findY)")
```

With this syntax you don't have to worry about the type of your variable.